# Background-image with linear gradient for colored header wont work on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, background-image, linear-gradients

I am trying to make colored header and it wont work on mobile browsers (header is not visible). Does someone know please why is this happening? Thank you very much.

Maybe it should be because of other code I have there.

HTML from Next.Js

```
<div className={indexStyles.sliderWrapper}>

              <div className="container">
                  <div className={indexStyles.sliderText}>
                      <h1>Autoslavkov</h1>
                      <ul>
                          <li>Autočalounictví</li>
                          <li>Autorizovaný chiptuning</li>
                          <li>Auto klimatizace</li>
                          <li>Renovace světel</li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>

              </div>

              <Image
                  src="/images/slid1.jpg"
                  alt=""
                  layout="fill"
                  objectFit="cover"
              />

          </div>
```

And CSS

```
.sliderWrapper{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    min-height: calc(100vh - var(--header-height) - var(--navInfo-height));
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sliderWrapper::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
}

.sliderText{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 65px 0 50px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Bold', sans-serif;
}

.sliderText h1{
     --hColor1: #bf1717;
     --hColor2: #E73636;
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, var(--hColor1), var(--hColor2) 50%, var(--hColor1));
     background-image: linear-gradient(to top, var(--hColor1), var(--hColor2) 50%, var(--hColor1));
     font-size: 30pt;
     -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
     background-clip: text;
     -webkit-background-clip: text;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 5px;
 }

.sliderText h1::after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: var(--hColor1);
}
```

Here is how it looks like on pc:

[image]

And here how it looks like on mobile:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I found that the `h1::after` property was doing this, but I dont know really why. I changed it to `position:absolute` and then to center it used `left:50%;` and `transform: translateX(-50%);` and now it works fine.